# Why wont my div icon go over my other div?

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

I have 3 cards, they show information about migrated, deleted or archived content sites. For Archived and Deleted cards the Icon2 sits on top of the info div, but for Migrated it is being pushed down and wont sit on top, so it being pushed off the bottom of the card. Why is this happening even though in my eyes they're all the same. I know I have 3 li's in the migrated card, but that should not matter.

```
<content id="template">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css"
    integrity="sha384-IIED/eyOkM6ihtOiQsX2zizxFBphgnv1zbe1bKA+njdFzkr6cDNy16jfIKWu4FNH"           >
  <style>
        #Container {
          width: 1200px;
          /*border: 1px solid gold;*/
          padding: 5px;
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: 2fr 2fr 2fr;
        }
    
        .Card {
            border: 2px solid gray;
            margin: 10px;
            height: 150px;
            transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
        }
    
        .Card:hover {
            transform: scale(1.05);
            border: 2px solid #6583ff ;
        }
    
        .Card:hover .Info {
            border-left: 2px solid #6583ff;
        }
    
        .Card.Arc 
            { background-color: #c6e2e9;
            }

      .Card.Mig 
          { background-color: #f1ffc4;
          }
      .Card.Del 
          { background-color: #ffcaaf;
          }
    
      .Icon {
          text-align: center;
          font-size: 3.5rem;
          display: inline-block;
          width:25%;
          height:75px;
          /*border: 1px solid red;*/
          margin: 5px;
          margin-top: 35px;
      }
    
      .Icon2 {
          font-size: 2rem;
          float: right;
          border: 1px solid red;
        position: relative;
      }
    
      .Info {
          word-wrap: break-word;
            font-size: 0.8rem;
            display: Inline-block;
            width: 63%;
            height:90%;
            border: 1px solid green;
            margin: 5px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            border-left: 2px solid gray;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
     
  </style>
    <div id="Container">
        {{#each . as |item|}}
            {{#if _A}}
                <div class="Card Arc">
                    <div class="Icon"><i class="fal fa-archive" style="color: #4d4d4d;"></i></div>
                        <div class="Info">{{Title}} - Archived
                        <li>Path to old site: {{Site_x0020_Address}}</li>
                        <li>Primary Contact: {{Site_x0020_Owners}}</li>
                        <div class="Icon2"><i class="fal fa-file-alt" style="color: #949494;"></i>    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {{/if}}
        {{#if _M}}
            <div class="Card Mig">
                <div class="Icon"><i class="far fa-cloud-upload" style="color: #4d4d4d;"></i></div>
                <div class="Info">{{Title}} - Migrated
                    <li>Path to old site: {{Site_x0020_Address}}</li>
                    <li>New Location: {{SPOnline_x0020_Site_x0020_Addres}}</li>
                    <li>Primary Contact: {{Site_x0020_Owners}}</li>
                    <div class="Icon2"><i class="fas fa-share" style="color: #949494;"></i></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {{/if}}
        {{#if _D}}
            <div class="Card Del">
                <div class="Icon"><i class="fal fa-trash-alt" style="color: #4d4d4d;"></i></div>
                <div class="Info">{{Title}} - Deleted
                    <li>Path to old site: {{Site_x0020_Address}}</li>
                    <li>Primary Contact: {{Site_x0020_Owners}}</li>
                    <div class="Icon2"><i class="fal fa-envelope" style="color: #949494;"></i></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

[What is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCFXt.png)

I would like the Migrated icon to go on top of the info div like the rest of them.

Comment: Because, it is overflowing the card element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem is the Card element is overflowing due to extra li's.

**Solution**

Using `flex` layout, I just wrapped the li and title in a div called Info-content and add `display:inline-flex` rule for Info element.

> li must always inside the ul or ol

```css
 #Container {
  width: 1200px;
  /*border: 1px solid gold;*/
  padding: 5px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 2fr 2fr;
}

.Card {
    border: 2px solid gray;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 150px;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    padding:5px;/* add this */
}

.Card:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
    border: 2px solid #6583ff ;
}

.Card:hover .Info {
    border-left: 2px solid #6583ff;
}

.Card.Arc 
    { background-color: #c6e2e9;
    }

.Card.Mig 
  { background-color: #f1ffc4;
  }
.Card.Del 
  { background-color: #ffcaaf;
  }

.Icon {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  width:25%;
  height:75px;
  /*border: 1px solid red;*/
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.Icon2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  align-self: end;
  /*float: right;*/
  border: 1px solid red;
 /*position: relative;*/
}

.Info {
  word-wrap: break-word;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    display: inline-flex;/* change this */
    width: 63%;
    height:100%;/* change this */
    border: 1px solid green;
    /*margin: 5px;*/
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-left: 2px solid gray;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.Info-content{
  flex: 0 0 85%;
  max-width: 88%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div id="Container">
            <div class="Card Mig">
                <div class="Icon"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload" style="color: #4d4d4d;"></i></div>
                <div class="Info">
                    <div class='Info-content'>
                       <span>{{Title}} - Migrated</span>
                   <ul>
                     <li>Path to old site: {{Site_x0020_Address}}</li>
                    <li>New Location: {{SPOnline_x0020_Site_x0020_Addres}}</li>
                    <li>Primary Contact: {{Site_x0020_Owners}}</li>
                   </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Icon2"><i class="fas fa-share" style="color: #949494;"></i></div>
                </div>
            </div>
                        <div class="Card Mig">
                <div class="Icon"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload" style="color: #4d4d4d;"></i></div>
                <div class="Info">
                <div class='Info-content'>
                    <span>{{Title}} - Migrated</span>
                    <ul>
                       <li>Path to old site: {{Site_x0020_Address}}</li>
                    <li>New Location: {{SPOnline_x0020_Site_x0020_Addres}}</li>
                    <li>Primary Contact: {{Site_x0020_Owners}}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                    <div class="Icon2"><i class="fas fa-share" style="color: #949494;"></i></div>
                </div>
            </div>
  <div class="Card Arc">
                    <div class="Icon"><i class="fa fa-archive" style="color: #4d4d4d;"></i></div>
                        <div class="Info">
                         <div class='Info-content'>
                            <span>{{Title}} - Archived</span>
                        <ul>
                          <li>Path to old site: {{Site_x0020_Address}}</li>
                        <li>Primary Contact: {{Site_x0020_Owners}}</li>
                        </ul>
                         </div>
                        <div class="Icon2"><i class="fa fa-file-alt" style="color: #949494;"></i>    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="Card Del">
                <div class="Icon"><i class="fa fa-trash-alt" style="color: #4d4d4d;"></i></div>
                <div class="Info">
               <div class='Info-content'>
                   <span>{{Title}} - Deleted</span>
                    <ul>
                      <li>Path to old site: {{Site_x0020_Address}}</li>
                    <li>Primary Contact: {{Site_x0020_Owners}}</li>
                    </ul>
               </div>
                    <div class="Icon2"><i class="fa fa-envelope" style="color: #949494;"></i></div>
                </div>
            </div>

</div>
```